# decomposing a string into known patterns

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching

Here's the python list of strings:

patterns = [
"KBKKB",
"BBBK",
"BKB",
"KBBB",
"KBB",
"BKBB",
"BBKB",
"KKBKB",
"BKBK",
"KBKB",
"KBKBK",
"BBK",
"BB",
"BKKB",
"BBB",
"KBBK",
"BKKBK",
"KB",
"KBKBK",
"KKBKKB",
"KBK",
"BBKBK",
"BBBB",
"BK",
"KKBKBK",
"KBBKB",
"BBKKB",
"KKKKBB",
"KKB"
]

I have an input string that consist of K and B only of arbitrary length. I want to know all the possible complete decompositions of the input string. Just an example a string of 8 B:

BBBBBBBB

Here are possible decompositions

BB BB BB BB BB

BBBB BBBB

BBBB BB BB

BB BB BBBB

BBB BBB BB

BB BBB BBB

Can anyone guide me how to go about it? I am not much concerned about efficiency right now.

Comment: Can you define a decomposition? Why isn't B B B B B B B B a possible decomposition? How is the other character relevant?

Comment: @Jason R. Coombs: `B` isn't allowed because it is not a member of the patterns list.

Comment: @Jason Because this is not a valid "weight". Actually I am working on Persian/Arabic Prosody. The project is open source under GPL at http://github.com/mohsinhijazee/Ustaad-Aasi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using recursion:

```
def getPossibleDecompositions(s):
    if s == '':
        yield []
    else:
        for pattern in patterns:
            if s.startswith(pattern):
                for x in getPossibleDecompositions(s[len(pattern):]):
                    yield [pattern] + x

for x in getPossibleDecompositions('BBBBBBBB'):
    print x
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be doing the job.